# how to make something unclickable for fixed period of time?

Tags: jquery

I have created animated slider and made possible to change images also by clicking next and previous button, but when you click the button while slide animation is on, it glitches, so I need to make the button unavailable to be clicked on until the animation is over. Is it possible and if so, how should I do it? 
Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your code, and ideally *also* a jsFiddle link? Just edit them into your question.

Comment: searching for .done()?

Comment: How do you animate element? Using CSS animation or jQuery or what? You have to post relevant infos in question. My guess, you should animate it using CSS class to fire animation and use specific CSS rule to hide buttons while animating element

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a variable indicating the state of any animations, and prevent any click logic happening while the animation is running. Something like this:

```
var animating = false;
$('#myElement').click(function() {
    animating = true;
    $(this).animate({ left: '100px' }, 500, function() {
        animating = false;
    });
});

$('#nextButton').click(function() {
    if (!animating) {
        // do something...
    }
});
```

Failing that, you could use `stop(true)` on the animating element to stop it at the current frame, before assigning a new animation to begin from it's current position.